# PHP execute nodejs from another server

Tags: php, node.js, web-scraping, chromium, puppeteer

I got an php application running on a shared host on the web. But there's an nodejs puppeteer script that runs on my personal computer to extract data from a website that only my user have privileges.
Is there a way to make the PHP app run the nodejs script, send parameters, wait for result and refresh the page after everything is done?

I've tried exec, but not working.

```
exec("node server:80/jsFunction.js --test=", $test);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways to deal with it. Most easiest and straightforward way would be to setup a server on your (or the target) computer and then simply pass on the request. This will be able to control node script and php script individually.

On your PHP file you can simply use `file_get_contents`,

```php
$text="some data to pass";
$homepage = file_get_contents("http://YOURPUBLICIPADDRESS:3000/?text=$text");
echo $homepage;
```

And on your node api, you can have some route which will handle the jsFunction from there, assuming it's a promise, I can probably use expressJS to handle it.

```
var express = require('express')
var jsFunction = require('./jsFunction')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  jsFunction(req.query.text).then(data=>res.send({data}))
})

app.listen(3000)
```